# Table content hidden by footer on iPhone

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having some problems on iphone while trying to show a "timeline" on iphone, the timeline is just a table with it's content.

The issue is that like if i have 30 rows on iphone there are shown just 28 while the other two are behind the footer and i'm able to show them only if i scroll not the div but entire page.

How can i set the height to the table in the way it's end on the footer start and not on the page end?

[image]

[image]

The page is build as the following (the table content is load dynamically)

```
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">

            <div class="card rounded-0" id="cardTav">
                <div id="bodyTavoli" class="card-body text-center">
                    <div class="table-responsive tableFixHead">
                        <table class="table table-hover" id="tableLine" border="0" style="border: none; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                            <thead id="timehead">
                                <tr>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="timeline">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
            </div>
        </footer>
```

Here is JSFiddle code (upper the container there is the nav) https://jsfiddle.net/3hvLwt6m/

Comment: sorry adding a codepen of your example will help

Comment: Can you not just add margin-bottom to the body to cover the footer? Please add the CSS/codepen for your example.

Comment: @AKASHPANDEY added jsfiddle

Comment: @Karl added jsfiddle code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please modify your css code changes are given below

**css**

```
.tableFixHead {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 70vh;
}
```

Comment: Actually i have yet tryed to play with max-height but that had no effect.. now with 70vh it fits perfectly

Comment: the issue with this approach is you are making the height of the scroll according to the vh which can increase and decrease which can cause responsive issues. that is what I feel. as 70vh may work for some cases but can fail in some cases as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

I think this will work try adding this in js fiddle you provided. I dont have a iphone so cant test.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify css as followed..

```
.tableFixHead {
    max-height: 70vh; 
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```